# Java Potential Bodmas Issue during calculation

Tags: java, math, logic

I am passing in these two values to my function...

```
    float c = -80f;
    float m = 1.66f;
```

The function takes in two floats which are used for contrast enhancement for an image, however during the if structure the program always enters the if else block, which is not correct. Therefore every value in the array is being assigned 255 which is incorrect, can anyone determine why this is the case?

```
//look up table for linear stretching
public short[] linearStretchLut(float m,float c)
{
    short Lut[] = new short[256];

    for(int i =0; i<Lut.length;i++){            
        if(i < -c/m){
            Lut[i] = 0;
        } else if(i > (255 - c) / m) {
            Lut[i] = 255;
        } else {
            Lut[i] = (short) (m*i+c);
        }
        System.out.println(i + " " + Lut[i]);
    }
    return Lut;
}
```

an example which should make the condition false...

i=10
10 > (255-c) / m
     (final value should be 201.8)
so this should be a false evaluation, the program does not replicate this behaviour though.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Set a breakpoint on the `Lut[i] = 255;` line, and see what values i, c and m have.

Answer (score 1):

The issues turned out to be this...

I was passing the variables m and c into the function in the wrong order, so the problem was of my own making :)

Answer (score 0):

I have created the below test program and it seems you were just passing the values in the wrong order:

```
package test;

public class Test {

    //look up table for linear stretching
    public static short[] linearStretchLut(float m,float c)
    {
        short Lut[] = new short[256];

        for(int i =0; i<Lut.length;i++){ 
            float f1 = -c/m;
            float f2 = (float) (255 - c) / m;
            if(i < f1){
                Lut[i] = 0;
            } else if(i > f2) {
                Lut[i] = 255;
            } else {
                Lut[i] = (short) (m*i+c);
            }
            System.out.println("-c/m = " + f1 + " / " + " (255 - c) / m = " + f2 + "/ i = " +  i + " / Lut[i] = " + Lut[i]);
        }
        return Lut;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        float c = -80f;
        float m = 1.66f;
        short Lut[] = Test.linearStretchLut(m,c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Woops, sorry, you answered while I was posting. Sorry!